# Case Chatter Feed - New Email button not appearing

Tags: lightning, email, chatter, page-layout

I am trying to enable the new Email button on our Case Chatter feed.   I have checked the following

1. System

   - Email-ToCase -> Enabled
   - Email Deliverability -> Enabled
   - Feed Tracking -> Case --> Enabled
2. Support Settings

   - Enable Case Feed Actions and Feed Items -> Enabled
3. Permissions granted

   - Send Email
   - Case Object -> Modify All, Create, etc...
4. Page Layouts

   - Quick Action -> Email Button added
   - Salesforce Mobile and Lightning Experience Actions -> Email Button added
   - Feed View -> Email Action Options - set

I attempted to add the Send Email to the Case Highlights buttons.  However this is no available under Actions -> Quick Actions

[image]

[image]